# Near-independence of Markov chain states

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Let $X(0), X(1), X(2), \ldots$ be an aperiodic irreducible Markov chain on a finite set. My intuition says that if $m$ is a very large number, then $$X(m), X(2m), X(3m), \ldots$$
should be nearly independent samples from the stationary distribution $\pi$ of the chain. What is a theorem to this effect?

Note: naturally, it is clear that each of $X(m), X(2m), \ldots$ will be a sample from something close to $\pi$ by the Markov chain convergence theorem. But how might one argue they are nearly independent? And what should the precise meaning of "nearly independent" be? These are the questions I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $k\geqslant1$ and every fixed sequence of states $(x_i)_{1\leqslant i\leqslant k+1}$,
$$
\mathbb P(X_{(k+1)m}=x_{k+1}\mid X_m=x_1,\ldots,X_{km}=x_k)=Q^m(x_k,x_{k+1}),
$$
where $Q$ is the transition matrix of the Markov chain $(X_n)_{n\geqslant0}$. Additionally, the chain is ergodic hence, when $m\to\infty$, $Q^m(x_k,x_{k+1})\to\pi(x_{k+1})$ and $\mathbb P(X_m=x_1)\to\pi(x_1)$. Bayes formula applied $k$ times yields
$$
\mathbb P(X_m=x_1,\ldots,X_{km}=x_k,X_{(k+1)m}=x_{k+1})\to\pi(x_1)\pi(x_2)\cdots\pi(x_{k+1}).
$$
Thus, for every fixed $k\geqslant1$, the distribution of the vector $(X_{im})_{1\leqslant i\leqslant k}$ converges to the distribution $\pi^{\otimes k}$ of an i.i.d. sample. Analogously, the distribution of the vector $(X_{im})_{0\leqslant i\leqslant k}$ converges to the distribution of an independent sample but the (limit) distribution of the first coordinate $X_0$ may differ from $\pi$.